# Spring @Validated annotation prevents @ConfigurationProproperties value injection, why?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, bean-validation, configurationproperties

I am trying with `@ConfigurationProperties` and I find two things:

- for tests to work, I have to put configuration properties files (yml) in `test` package; setters and an empty constructor are required.
- If I annotated the class with `@Validated`, injection just fails with all `null` values.

If you say the first one is understandable, and the second one? Why?

The purpose is to validate configuration properties injection, so that crucial properties values should not be absent when the application launches.

I have this yaml to map:

```
accertify:
  fr:
    merchant1:
      host: "sandbox.accertify.dev"
      protocol: "https"
      user: "fraud"
      password: "temporal"
      merchant: "merchant1FR"
    merchant2:
      host: "sandbox.accertify.dev"
      protocol: "https"
      user: "fraud"
      password: "temporal"
      merchant: "merchant2FR"
  es:
    merchant1:
      host: "sandbox.accertify.dev"
      protocol: "https"
      user: "fraud"
      password: "temporal"
      merchant: "merchant1ES"
    merchant2:
      host: "sandbox.accertify.dev"
      protocol: "https"
      user: "fraud"
      password: "temporal"
      merchant: "merchant2ES"
```

I have this class to mapping nested configurations:

```
import com.westerngun.fraud.jfps.dto.provider.accertify.country.ConfigurationEs;
import com.westerngun.fraud.jfps.dto.provider.accertify.country.ConfigurationFr;
import com.westerngun.fraud.jfps.service.client.ConnectionDetailsInterface;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;

import javax.validation.Valid;

/**
 * Class to read Accertify provider connection credentials.
 */
@Getter
@Setter
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "accertify")
@Validated   // <--- this seems the problem
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class AccertifyConnectionDetail extends ConnectionDetails {

    @Valid
    private ConfigurationFr fr;

    @Valid
    private ConfigurationEs es;
}
```

And, its interface:

```
public abstract class ConnectionDetails {
    public abstract ConfigurationFr getFr();
    public abstract ConfigurationEs getEs();
}
```

And, `ConfigurationEs` and `ConfigurationFr` are both subclass of:

```
@Component
public class CountryConfigDetail {
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Valid
    private Merchant1 merchant1;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Valid
    private Merchant2 merchant2;
}
```

`Merchant1` and `Merchant2` are subclass of :

```
@Data
@Component
public class MerchantConfigDetail {

    @NotEmpty
    @NotNull
    private String user;

    @NotEmpty
    @NotNull
    private String password;

    ...
    @NotEmpty
    @NotNull
    private Map<String, String> headers;
}
```

When I try to inject into some `@Autowired` tests without `@Validated` in the first class, it works(`fr` and `es` have values in the yml file)

[image]

When I add @Validated, `fr` and `es` are null.

Test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class AccertifyConfigurationTest {

    @Autowired
    private AccertifyConnectionDetail accertifyConnectionDetail; // <--- this field should be injected


    @Test
    public void givenAAccertifyClientService_WhenClientIsBuild_ShouldHaveTheProviderConfigurationCorrect() {
        AccertifyConfiguration accertifyConfiguration = new AccertifyConfiguration(accertifyConnectionDetail);
        accertifyConfiguration.buildConfiguration("FR", "Merchant1");

        Assert.assertEquals("fraud", accertifyConfiguration.getUser());
        Assert.assertEquals("temporal", accertifyConfiguration.getPassword());
        Assert.assertTrue(accertifyConfiguration.getHost().startsWith("sandbox.accertify."));
        Assert.assertEquals("merchant1FR", accertifyConfiguration.getMerchantCode());
    }
...
```

Comment: Please add some code for this question, doesn't see correct from my usage.

Comment: Add your test as code not as images. You are using proxies so you are probably doing things  you shouldn't be doing in the first place. Next to that you probably don't want `@Configuration` on a `@ConfigurationProperties` class.

Comment: I change `@Configuration` to `@Component` and the proxy turns into real objects. And with `@Validated` it still holds all null. About `@Configuration` and `@ConfigurationProperties` you are right.

Comment: Ofcourse they are `null` as you aren't creating them. The framework will not create a new instance, you will have to do that yourself when initializing the field. Check the [`ServerProperties`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ServerProperties.java) which instantiates the nested properties before hand. Only fields for which a converter or editor exists will be created, others, for binding, you have to create yourself.

Comment: What I meant was, without `@Validated`, when I debug into these lines, `accertifyConnectionDetail` is `@Autowired` correctly, the values are read from yaml files and they hold non-null, as the image shows, because Spring knows it is `@ConfigurationProperties`; but, only by un-commenting `@Validated`, autowiring does not work.

Comment: I face the same problem: trying to inject a `@ConfigurationProperties` bean in a `@Configuration` class. Configuration properties correctly set ... until I annotate it with `@Validated`. What boot version are you using ?

Comment: I am with 2.1.1.RELEASE

Comment: it seems that this issue still exist   https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/8173     have you found a workaround

Comment: No, I don't have solution yet. For now I don't use `@Validated`.