# @ConfigurationProperties with @Validated don’t bind configuration values in integration tests

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-test, configurationproperties

I have a validated configuration properties class.

```
@Data
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "notifications")
@Validated
public class NotificationConfig {
    @NotNull
    @Valid
    private NotificationMessageConfig message = new NotificationMessageConfig();
    @NotNull
    @Valid
    private SmsConfig sms = new SmsConfig();
    @NotNull
    @Valid
    private EmailConfig email = new EmailConfig();
    @NotNull
    @Valid
    private NotificationTimerConfig timer = new NotificationTimerConfig();
}
```

In integration tests, I am trying to autowire the bean of the class. On runtime, I have an autowired bean but this bean has null values instead of bound configuration.
**Note!** If I remove @Validated annotation, I will have a valid bean but the config will not be validated.

```
@Slf4j
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class NotificationsIT extends BaseIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    private Notifications notification;
    @Autowired
    private Banks banks;
    @Autowired
    private NotificationConfig notificationConfig;

   @BeforeEach
    public void init() {
        super.init();
    // notificationConfig autowired but fields have null values
        defaultNotificationConfig = clone(notificationConfig);
    }
}
```

Comment: Check the 5th header of this page : https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-testing-configurationproperties

Comment: @AjayNegi Good article, but it is not my case(
I have to use @SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
To use one application instance for all integration tests...

Comment: But I tried some things from the article like
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer.class)
@EnableConfigurationProperties(value = ServerConfig.class)
It did't help, unfortuanetly

Comment: @WesternGun maybe you can help.... You posted some familiar information here.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31745168/how-to-test-classes-with-configurationproperties-and-autowired

Comment: @MaksymKmets I think, you have the same issue like in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55471653/spring-validated-annotation-prevents-configurationproproperties-value-injectio

Comment: @saver is the issuer is familiar to [discribe in proposed question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55471653/spring-validated-annotation-prevents-configurationproproperties-value-injectio)